# tornado URL and HTML form

Tags: python, html, tornado

I'm using tornado and I want to Insert something to my MongoDB from values in a HTML form.

in the HTML file I have a form like this:

```
<form method="get" >
```

with 2 textbox and a submit button.
and I don't know what to set as "action"

I have a handler class with a function called "post" like bellow:

```
 class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
     name  = self.get_argument("Name", "")
     index = self.get_argument("Index","")
      .... code for updating MongoDB
```

I have a file called BaseUrl.py that contains:

```
(/admin/edit[/]?',MyHandler  )
```

but it seems that the "post" function in myHandler does not execute.
could you please give me some advice about how to properly set my URLs and form actions?

Answer (score 2):

Change the form method to POST as you are handling in a POST request:

```
<form method="POST" >
```

You also need to provide an action if the form is served from different page, so your form should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/edit">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post method isn't called because your form specifies `method="get"`. Change that to `method="post"` and it'll probably work.

If the action is empty the browser will submit the request to the current page, so if you have a get handler serving the form at the same URL you don't need to specify it.

Comment: thank you user3763140, but I have changed my method to "post" and it still does not work, I think there must be another problem.

Comment: What page are you on when you're filling out the form? If it's /admin/edit you don't need the action attribute, if not then adding `action="/admin/edit"` is necesssary.