# How can I get data from html using python tornado

Tags: python, html, input, tornado

How can I get data (html input) using python-tornado.

python code is this:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.httpserver

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.render("index.html")

def post(self):
    title = self.get_argument("title")
    self.render("second.html")

app = tornado.web.Application([
(r"/", MainHandler),
])

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(8080)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

and html source code is this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post"></form>
<div style="margin-bottom:5px">
<input name="title" type="text"/> 
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this guy has [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342974/tornado-url-and-html-form)

```
class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
 name  = self.get_argument("Name", "")
 index = self.get_argument("Index","")
  .... code for updating MongoDB
```